# I want to display the country list based on German and English language

Tags: node.js, country

I'm using npm 'country-data'. I need to display the country based on German and English language & also in alphabetical order.

```
    this.stateOptions = [];
    lodash.each(countries.all, (state) => {
        if (state.status !== 'assigned') {
            return;
        }
        console.log(state)
        this.stateOptions.push({
            value: state.alpha2,
            label: state.name
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this [i18n-iso-countries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n-iso-countries). May It's will help you.

Installing
Install it using npm: npm install i18n-iso-countries

```
var countries = require("i18n-iso-countries");
```

If you use i18n-iso-countries with Node.js your are done. If you use the package in a browser environment you also have to register the languages you want to use to minimize file size.

// Support french & english languages.

```
countries.registerLocale(require("i18n-iso-countries/langs/en.json"));
countries.registerLocale(require("i18n-iso-countries/langs/fr.json"));
```

Code to Country
Get the name of a country by its ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2, Alpha-3 or Numeric code  // this is important

```
 var countries = require("i18n-iso-countries");
```

// in a browser environment:

```
countries.registerLocale(require("i18n-iso-countries/langs/en.json"));
console.log("US (Alpha-2) => " + countries.getName("US", "en")); // United States of America
console.log("US (Alpha-2) => " + countries.getName("US", "de")); // Vereinigte Staaten von Amerika
console.log("USA (Alpha-3) => " + countries.getName("USA", "en")); // United States of America
console.log("USA (Numeric) => " + countries.getName("840", "en")); /
```